# How to reverse a string using a while loop in java?

Tags: java, string, while-loop

I have a task, and I need to make the code take in a user inputted word, put it in capital letters, reverse and it output it. This is my code so far, but I really have no clue how I do it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordSizeChecker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a word: ");
        String oword = kb.nextLine();
        String word = oword.toUpperCase();
        int length = word.length();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < length)
        {
            System.out.println(word.substring(i,length));
            length--;
        }

    }

}
```

Output:

> Please enter a word: chess
>   CHESS
>   CHES
>   CHE
>   CH
>   C

Comment: Work it out on paper, as what you would do with a word like CHESS to reverse it. And turn that in a true algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

```
new StringBuilder(oword).reverse().toString().toUpperCase();
```

or with a loop

```
oword = oword.toUpperCase();
for(int i = oword.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    System.out.print(oword.charAt(i));
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: while this is a very nice answer, this doesn't use an explicit while loop as the homework requested :)

Comment: Overread that, you are right :) I recommend to use the charAt() function then.

Comment: Ahaha. Works for sure but i think its missing the excercise's point

Comment: I would have failed that exercise. What a shame :D Adapted the solution for the exercise as well.

Comment: `StringBuilder` doesn't have a `toUpperCase()` method, so move it last.

Comment: This is not correct. What if you have  characters in the string?

Comment: Is there anyway to get around this without using StringBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a word: ");
    String oword = kb.nextLine();
    String word = oword.toUpperCase();
    int length = word.length();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // start from the end of the input string
    int i = length - 1;
    while (i >= 0) {
      // add the "next" character to the output
      sb.append(word.charAt(i));
      // step 1 character back
      i--;
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: Try this with the String "      "

Comment: @Ingo in that case, you'd use `StringBuilder#reverse()`, though I doubt this is a requirement of his task.

Comment: It is, as there are no restrictions of what the user may type.

Comment: What's the problem with unicode characters? It works.

Comment: Not with the example string from above.

Comment: Well, I think it's fair enough to expect these kind of homeworks to work on ASCII only, unless otherwise stated in the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
String original, reverse = "";
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Enter a string to reverse");
  original = in.nextLine();

  int length = original.length();

  for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
     reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);

  System.out.println("Reverse of entered string is: "+reverse);
```